# Insert unqiue record into one table and the results into a second table

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL and PHP, I have two tables ResponseTable and EntryTable

Response table has

```
 RespID(pk,uq,ai, int), Response(string)
```

Entry table has

```
 EntryID(pk,uq,ai,int), RespID(int), UserID(int)
```

I would like to insert a response into the ResponseTable where the Response doesn't exist, and then insert an entry into the EntryTable based on the RespID from the ResponseTable corresponding to the response.

How can this be done with the fewest statements?

EDIT:
Response is unique

Comment: It has to be two queries... you can't do two inserts into two separate tables in a single query.

Comment: You can use a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fewest statements from the front-end would be to use a stored procedure.  Any way you do it, though, you will still need to have two INSERT statements. You just can't insert two different things with one query.

Answer (score 0):

mysql supports [TRIGGERS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) . you can add one to your ResponseTable that will activate "AFTER" "INSERT" and you can get it to use the values that are being inserted using the NEW key word.

the body of the trigger can be an insert into entry

something like:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `response_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `response`
  FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN INSERT INTO entry SET RespID=NEW.RespID ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE operation=1;END;
```

So once you have your trigger set up, any time you do an insert on respnse, the trigger will get activated

Comment: Reading your answer, I believe yours solution would work the best for what I asked... not what I need sorry, and I will credit you with it.  Will this type of solution work when the response string is unique?  Basically, the response table holds unique responses which the other table links to.

Comment: Could I use the "Before Insert" to add it to the entrytable and then in my case (again not part of the info I gave), 'on duplicate key update' an instance count column?

Comment: Oh, another question where do I get the additional information in this case userid from which is not part of the responsetable insert?

Comment: @vbbartlett yes, yes you COULD, further information can be obtained from other tables via a SELECT with a JOIN. these questions are a bit unclear, try to clarify if you can